# Is it possible to infer/derive different types based on object properties?

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

Is it possible in TypeScript, from this data:

```
const data = {
  field1: {values: ['a', 'b', 'c']},
  field2: {values: ['c', 'd', 'e'], multiple: true}
}

const fields = someFunction(data)
```

To infer/derive the following return value of `someFunction` (and hence type of `fields`), based on whether `multiple` exists or not (or if it's true or not, if that makes things easier)?

```
type FieldsType = {
  field1: 'a' | 'b' | 'c',
  field2: ('c' | 'd' | 'e')[]
}
```

`data` can be `as const` if that's what's required.

Comment: TypeScript has quite a bit of inference capability: the best answer will require more information from you: What exactly do you want to infer? The `FieldsType` type that you showed doesn't correspond to the `data` value. Are you looking to derive a type using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)? `const data = { /* ... */ } as const; type FieldsType = typeof data;`

Comment: The [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74695897/2) question is still not clear. Are you maybe looking for something like this? https://tsplay.dev/WkOK2W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you want a type for your source data:

```
type Data = Record<string, {
  values: readonly string[],
  multiple?: boolean
}>
```

Then you can make a mapped conditional type that accepts that:

```
type Fields<T extends Data> = {
  [K in keyof T]:
    T[K]['multiple'] extends true
      ? T[K]['values'][number][]
      : T[K]['values'][number]
}
```

This type maps over all keys in `T` (`field1` and `field2`), and resolve the value type of that property as a conditional type.

That conditional type says that if `T[K]['multiple'] extends true` then returns an array of the member type of the `values` of that property, else return a non-array of that type.

You can now use that type like:

```
function someFunction<T extends Data>(data: T): Fields<T> {
  // TODO: implement this
}
```

Which does what you expect:

```
const fields = someFunction({
  field1: { values: ['a', 'b', 'c'] },
  field2: { values: ['c', 'd', 'e'], multiple: true }
} as const)

fields.field1 // ('a' | 'b' | 'c')[]
fields.field2 // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIAiBDcz4F54CVYGMB7AJwBMAeAZ3CIEsA7AcwBp4BvUeeAN2QBsBXWBQBc8IrGQkCdXpHhVajANoBdJh3gBbfr3A1ovWAH5RAIwIFDyOqAC+APlAQYCAGI1YvEhTIAVeLAAHuCwdN5IqMj2mGwaSgDS8PTwANawkAQAZvC+KsIanL4JKkoA5Nq6+oalKgHBoeHUggWc8EY5xWU8AkI1SnT8mqawRCotnKJF8SWl3YIUfQNDIyVjILZOICT4vMji8Jn8dHh60vIEmrCuRyc00n51IWEUEWj2ABQkkZMAlKLunm8fkcYBAhDoVAOHi8LywFAuVxupzo73YIE4mWhJAAjKJWNw+PNRGVkKUWKVTGT4KU8DV4LZ1OioYCAEx4gk9ETwMq08kkKmlWA1FgVPQGWCiJoIDbreDIF7gqg-TaYwEUAB0qq82NAAHpda1OAA9IwqrEarUkFl6g2Gk1AA)

Comment: Thank you, the `[K in keyof T]` was the information I was looking for.